# Regex: Match URLs for specific domain EXCEPT when a certain querystring parameter has a certain value

Tags: regex, url

In short, I need to match all URLs in a block of text that are for a certain domain and don't contain a specific querystring parameter and value (refer=twitter)

I have the following regex to match all URLs for the domain.

```
\b(https?://)?([a-z0-9-]+\.)*example\.com(/[^\s]*)?
```

I just can't get the last part to work

```
(?![&?]refer=twitter)\b(https?://)?([a-z0-9-]+\.)*example\.com(/[^\s]*)?
```

So the following SHOULD match

```
example.com
http://example.com/
https://www.example.com#link
www.example.com?somevalue=foo
```

But these should NOT

```
https://www.anotherexample.com#link
www.example.com?refer=twitter
```

EDIT:
  And if you can get it to match the

```
http://example.com?foo=foo.bar
```

out of a sentence like

```
For examples go to http://example.com?foo=foo.bar.
```

without picking up the period, that would be great!

EDIT2:
  Fixed the trailing period issue with this

```
\b(https?://)?([a-z0-9-]+\.)*example\.com/?([^\s]*[^.])?
```

EDIT3: 
  This seems to work, or at least 99% of the tests I've thrown at it

```
(?!\b.*[&?]refer=twitter)\b(https?://)?([a-z0-9-]+\.)*example\.com/?([^\s]*[^.])?
```

EDIT4:
  Settled on

```
\b(?!.*[&?]refer=twitter)(https?://)?([a-z0-9-]+\.)*nygard\.com(?!\.)[^\s]*\b+
```

Comment: And can we refrain from the "Now you have two problems" comments

Comment: Regex for pulling URLs out of user generated text are nearly impossible. You have three problems: no control over the input and the usual two regex problems. :)

Comment: You say "Nearly impossible", which by definition, means it's possible.

Comment: Why must this all happen in a single regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?!\b.*[&?]refer=twitter)
```

Is what you're looking for.

Comment: I beat you by a few minutes! lol nice work though, I've almost perfected the regex to work 99.9% with the caveat that if they don't put a space after the trailing punctuation (period, explamation point, etc) it fails, but that's impossible to differentiate.  I just have to clean up the very end of the regex a little more and it'll be ready.    (?!\b.*[&?]refer=twitter)\b(https?://)?([a-z0-9-]+\.)*example\.com[^\s]*\b+

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, at first the thought of using a regex didn't even cross my mind (which is a good sign - using a regex must, IMO, always be a secondary option, not primary). Here is how I'd do it in my language of choice

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> p = urlparse(r'http://foo.bar.com/baz?refer=twitter&rock=paper')
>>> parse_qs(p.query)
{'rock': ['paper'], 'refer': ['twitter']}
```

You can do anything from here.

Comment: For the record, I didn't down vote you.  I personally don't see why people think regex's are a last resort and dislike them.  I find them to be a good solution, simpler to write, and less error prone than lots of string parsing and manipulation to complete a task, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Well, you are contradicting yourself. First you ask a question about how you can't get some regexes to work, but then you say, they are less error-prone. On the other hand, I don't see how one could possibly get wrong two calls to the standard library function (as in my example). I am not saying, that regular expressions should not be learned, not at all. In fact my attitude towards them stems from my experience (sometimes good, sometimes bad).

Comment: "Well, you are contradicting yourself. First you ask a question about how you can't get some regexes to work, but then you say, they are less error-prone."  That is not contradictory at all.  There is one point of failure in a regex.  The regex itself, and it's purpose is to parse and validate strings of data.  Why would I want to recreate that in several lines of code?  It's much more likely I write flawed code, than a flawed regex.

Comment: I don't know about you, I've been a regex fanatic for quite some time. Then I've started writing unit tests.

Comment: And what does unit tests have to do with using a regex or not?  You can write unit tests for regexes too.